# ExtJS 4 MVC Ajax CRUD Grid with PHP and MySQL - JSON not working

Tags: php, mysql, extjs, http-headers, crud

In order to learn crud operations in extjs using php and MySql I was referring to the following example:

http://www.loiane.com/2012/05/extjs-4-mvc-ajax-crud-grid-com-php-e-mysql-json/

(source code is available [here](https://github.com/loiane/extjs4-mvc-json-crud-php-mysql))

As I try to perform crud operations in the database, the data is neither getting saved nor retrieved despite the status code being 200 (i.e. OK) in the header.

I would really appreciate if someone could please guide me regarding the issue that is causing the application to behave in the undesired manner.

the database name is 'blog'
& the table name is 'contact'.

[image]

[image]

[image: Response Tab]

Comment: What do you get returned from the server (response tab in the screenshots you've added)

Comment: @JimL I have added the response tab 's screenshot for your reference

Comment: Ok, so clearly you've got an error somewhere. It's returning 200 OK because that's the standard "requested resource delivered" status. But you definitely don't want to return your PHP source code. Does your PHP files work if you access them directly in the browser? Just to make sure your web server is set up to actually serve PHP

Comment: @JimL Thanks a lot......... The issue is resolved.....
Actually the issue was with the web server.....